# Complex sorting on association in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

I have three model `Hotel`, `Package`, `PackagePrice`, and association are like:

Hotel can have many packages and each package has one packageprice

Models are:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :excel_sheet, :excel_sheet_file_name
  attr_accessible :hotel_name, :stars, :location, :searchable, :excel_sheet, :excel_sheet_file_name

  has_many :package_prices, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :packages, :through => :package_prices, :order => 'package_prices.price'
end


class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :package_name
  has_many :package_prices, :dependent => :destroy, :order => 'price DESC'
  has_many :hotels, :through => :package_prices, :order => 'package.package_prices.price'
end

class PackagePrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price, :package_id, :hotel_id
  belongs_to :package
  belongs_to :hotel
end
```

and corresponding tables are:

```
mysql> desc hotels
    -> ;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| hotel_name | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| stars      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| location   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| searchable | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 1       |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc packages;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| package_name | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc package_prices;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| package_id | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price      | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| hotel_id   | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I have hotels records in a variable `@hotels` and I want to filter this `@hotels` by `price` in `asc or desc` order. So please help me to find out this query.

Comment: If each hotel can have multiple prices, which price do you want to use to sort by?

Comment: @Slicedpan I want to sort hotels by price in lowest to highter

Answer (score 2):

You would do that using this,

```
@hotels = Hotel.joins(:package_prices).order('package_prices.price')
```

However I don't think your models are set up the way you described, so I'm not sure if this will do what you want